# error in uploading image in product

Tags: magento-1.9

i am uploading product images through admin panel but when i upload image then error and not showing any error

i am use code for showing error

```
public function save($destinationFolder, $newFileName = null){
$this->_validateFile();

if ($this->_allowCreateFolders) {
    $this->_createDestinationFolder($destinationFolder);
}

if (!is_writable($destinationFolder)) {
    // Put a mage::log() and check what is the folder magento is looking for.
    Mage::log($destinationFolder);
    throw new Exception('Destination folder is not writable or does not exists.');
}
```

. . . . .

}

please help me

[image: image is not upload]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission issue with your media directory.

If you have just upgraded to 1.9.2.3. Magento changed the file permission in the Varien_File_Uploader class.

You can set the correct file permissions using the documentation on the Magento [site](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html) However if it's a live site I would make sure to back it up and put it into maintenance mode. If you are not comfortable with changing file permissions I would contact your hosting company.

I would also enable logging and check the logs to see what the exact error is in case it's not a file permission error.

Comment: ok i will try with given details

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: No it's not solved yet

Comment: Sorry. I missed your message. Did you apply the latest patch 1.9.2.4. This makes changes to Varien_File_Uploader class.